# Xubuntu 18.04 XFCE 4.12 window manager keyboard shortcuts not working with Apple Aluminium Keyboard model

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, xfce, window-manager, apple

Settings in **Keyboard > Layout > Keyboard model** are set it to Apple Aluminium

Keyboard shortcuts specified under **Window Manager > Keyboard** have no effect at all. I can't cycle through windows using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> and closing with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> also doesn't work.

I can set the shortcuts, so the keys are being recognized and other system-wide hotkeys defined in **Keyboard > Application Shortcuts**, such as launching a new terminal, are working fine.

I've tried:

- using a different keyboard (with settings left unchanged)
- changing layouts
- changing window manager themes

What works:

- using a different keyboard model and keyboard (tried a Dell)
- using the shortcuts in Chromium

It seems that XFCE window manager shortcuts and the keyboard model Apple Aluminium don't work at all.

What could cause this? Is there a work around?